# What happens to Saruman when he goes after Sauron?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

In the Hobbit movie: Saruman says to leave Sauron with him. What really happens?

Comment: This scene is a movie invention; unless it's discussed in either the extended edition or the DVD commentary, I doubt there's going to be a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no evidence in the theatrical release of the movie to say "what really happens".

There may be scenes treating this in the extended edition, but pending that release there is nothing to allow any definitive conclusion one way or another.

In the book, the whole "Battle of Dol Guldur" scene is not present. The best we get is the narrator's description:

> It appeared that Gandalf had been to a great council of the white wizards, masters of lore and good magic; and that they had at last driven the Necromancer from his dark hold in the south of Mirkwood.

(*The Hobbit*, Chapter 19, "The Last Stage")

Comment: Having not read the books, I assumed this was Saruman's way of telling the audience he had decided to join Sauron.

Answer (score 0):

That line is simply Saruman showing the Council how confident he was, both in his own ability and Sauron's weakness.

In the books, we see that it was at that Council that Saruman "revealed" that the Ring had passed down the Anduin and into the Sea, effectively making it irretrievable.

He was confident because :

1. Sauron hadn't shown himself for thousands of years.
2. Saruman thought he'd be able to track down the Ring and challenge Sauron himself.
3. As the leader of the Council, by being confident, he was placating any doubts in the rest of the Council, who would be his primary opposition should they discover his plan.

Saruman is still completely on the side of good at this time, at least openly. It's not until the Ring is found that he shows his true colors.